# How to get Ticker symbol from table using jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to get the symbols from the table at [YahooFinance](https://finance.yahoo.com/trending-tickers), but can't figure out why my code doesn't detect the table.

This is what I tried:

```
public String[] getTrendingTickers() {
    String[] trendingTickers = new String[30];
    int numTickers = 0;
    String url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/trending-tickers/";
    try {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        for (Element row : document.select("table.W(100%) tr")) {
            String ticker = row.select(
                    ".Fz\\(s\\).Ta\\(start\\)\\!.Bgc\\(\\$lv2BgColor\\).Z\\(1\\).Bgc\\(\\$lv3BgColor\\).Pos\\(st\\).simpTblRow\\:h_Bgc\\(\\$hoverBgColor\\).Pend\\(10px\\).Start\\(0\\).Pend\\(15px\\).Pstart\\(6px\\).Ta\\(start\\).Va\\(m\\)")
                    .text();
            System.out.println(ticker);
            trendingTickers[numTickers] = ticker;
            numTickers++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return trendingTickers;
}
```

With the error `org.jsoup.select.Selector$SelectorParseException: Could not parse query 'table.W(100%).tr': unexpected token at '(100%).tr'`

Comment: I'm not clear on what you intend to happen with the `(100%)` section of the selector. Can you explain what you are expecting it to do?

Comment: The `(100%)` is part of the table id in the html (`W(100%)`).

Comment: No that's not how selectors work. I'll post some sample code as an answer so you can see how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Ah I see what you are trying to do - that is the class name for the table. Unfortunately jsoup doesn't handle special characters in class names well (AFAIK). But I think there's only 1 table in the html anyway so I think you can just select on table as in the code I posted

Comment: The page you're trying to parse throws a parsing error when tried to load via https://try.jsoup.org/

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code that creates a list of all the symbols in the table of the page you reference:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://finance.yahoo.com/trending-tickers/").get();
Element table = document.select("table tbody").first();
List<String> symbols = new ArrayList<>();
for (Element row: table.select("tr")) {
    symbols.add(row.select("td").first().text());
}
System.out.println(symbols);
```

See https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html for details on the selector syntax.